# I'm looking for a horror anthology from the 80's or the 90's!

Tags: story-identification

It includes two stories that I vaguely remember,the first is about a young girl who goes to stay with relatives and comes to believe that her cousin is a vampire!! And the second is about a self aware pumpkin sitting in a crate waiting  for someone to purchase him,at the end of the story an old lady comes along with the intent of making a pumpkin pie!! I'm almost certain that it also had poems or chants. The name of the book was called something like witches, werewolves,and vampires...

Comment: [Rod Serling's Triple W: Witches, Warlocks and Werewolves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rod_Serling%27s_Triple_W:_Witches,_Warlocks_and_Werewolves?)?

Comment: [Werewolves, Ghosts and Vampires](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?130349) by Diane Woo?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange. Please make sure you've checked out the [tour], read [ask] (and possibly [answer]), as well as the [Story-ID guidelines](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info). What language did you read it in? Where were you when you read it? Medium? Etc. I hope you decide to stick around!